# Spring @SubscribeMapping being called

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, stompjs

i am trying to make a webpage for multiplayer games similar to the jackbox party pack series.

I want to do this by creating sessions/rooms which are identified by a randomly generated 4 letter sequence.I am using spring as a backend and react.js with stomp-js as a frontend.

Now for my prototype i am making a chat application. And i want to send the whole chat log when a user subscribes to the the session. The url the client subscribes to should be "/topic/{roomCode}".

my spring SocketConfiguration looks like this

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

To do this i've got a controler in spring that has this method:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/topic/{gameCode}")
public Message joinGame(@DestinationVariable String gameCode){

    System.out.println("This method has been called");
    return sessions.joinGame(gameCode);
}
```

But this method never gets called. I have confirmed this using the debugger in inteliJ.
I can send messages fine just the subscribtion mapping doesn't work.
Just to be sure though here is the method used to send messages to the clients:

```
@MessageMapping("/{gameCode}")
@SendTo("/topic/{gameCode}")
public Message test(Message message, @DestinationVariable String gameCode ){

    Game game = sessions.get(gameCode).getGame();
    return game.changeStatus(message);
}
```

In my react.js app i've got this bit of code for connecting and receiving/sending messages:
(please don't judge me for using class based components)

```
initializeChat() {

    const client = new Client({

        brokerURL: "ws://localhost:8080/stomp-endpoint",
        debug: (str) => console.log(str)
    })

    client.onConnect = this.subscribe.bind(this, client)
    client.activate()
    return client
}

subscribe(client){

    let sessionCode = this.props.session.code
    client.subscribe("/topic/"+ sessionCode,this.receiveMessage)
}

sendMessage(e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    let sessionCode = this.props.session.code;
    let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    this.state.connection.publish({ destination: '/topic/'+sessionCode, body: message });
}

receiveMessage(message) {

    let appendMessage = message.body+"<br>"
    let history = document.getElementById("history")
    history.append(appendMessage)
}
```

I've tried to switch the subscribe mapping to "/{gamecode}" which yielded the same result.

Comment: I have now added a event listener to make sure the subscription actualy arrives. it does seem to arive and the event includes a message with the header "simpDestination":"/topic/HEVT" where HEVT is a session code. I do not get why it's not using the subscribe mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a fix but don't know why this fixes it so if anyone can pitch in for that i would wecome it.

adding "/topic" to the ApplicationDestinationPrefixes fixed it.
My config looks like this now:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app","/topic");
    
}
```